# Animating a QGraphicsTextItem by sublassing QGraphicsObject

Tags: python, pyqt5

I wish to animate a QGraphicsTextItem. I have learnt that it itself doesnt have pos attribute so with references from here : [QGraphicsObject with QPropertyAnimation in PyQt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654373/qgraphicsobject-with-qpropertyanimation-in-pyqt)
I created the following:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation, QParallelAnimationGroup
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsScene, QApplication,QGraphicsTextItem, QGraphicsObject

import bubble_sort
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class label_Creator(QGraphicsObject):
def getLabel(self, i):
    label = QGraphicsTextItem(str(i))
    return label

class Ui_MainWindow():
    lable_map = {}
    arr = [5,9,1,7,2,4]
    creator = label_Creator()
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1322, 887)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.start_but = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.start_but.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1240, 530, 75, 31))
        self.start_but.setObjectName("ins_but")
        self.inp_arr = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.inp_arr.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1083, 530, 141, 31))
        self.inp_arr.setObjectName("inp_arr")
        self.graphicsView = 
        QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 70, 1151, 
        181))
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)
        self.graphicsView.show()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


        self.sketch(self.arr)
        self.start_but.clicked.connect(self.start_sequence)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", 
        "MainWindow"))
        self.start_but.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))


'''
sketch redraws a scene everytime after clearing it. It iterates 
through the array and forward is the initial X coordinate.
For each successive text item, forward is incremented by 70 so that 
there is some space between different array elements.
Also I store the reference of this label into a dictionary called 
label_map which I use later for animation
'''
def sketch(self,arr):
    self.scene.clear()

    forward = 100
    for i in arr:
        label = self.creator.getLabel(i)
        self.lable_map[i] = label
        pos_point = QtCore.QPoint(forward, 160)
        label.setPos(pos_point)
        forward = forward + 70
        self.scene.addItem(label)
    print(self.lable_map)



def start_sequence(self):
    bubble_sort.bubble.bubbleSort(self, self.arr)

'''
I obtain the larger and smaller swappable element from the bubble 
sort function. Then using the integer value I obtain
the associated label reference from the dictionary I created during 
sketch. I then take the start and end pos of the 
text and put them into two animations, one animation for smaller 
label and other for larger label.
The scene.update or processEvents call are my desperate attempts to 
see if anything else works.
'''

def onbtnclick(self, larger, smaller):
    print("check1")
    label_small = self.lable_map[smaller]
    label_larger = self.lable_map[larger]
    start_pos = label_small.pos()
    end_pos = label_larger.pos()
    animation_group = QParallelAnimationGroup(self)
    print("check2")

    animation = QPropertyAnimation(
        self,
        propertyName=b"pos",
        targetObject=label_larger,
        startValue=start_pos,
        endValue=end_pos,
        duration=8000,
    )


    animation2 = QPropertyAnimation(
        self,
        propertyName=b"pos",
        targetObject=label_small,
        startValue=end_pos,
        endValue=start_pos,
        duration=8000,
    )
    print("check3")
    animation_group.addAnimation(animation)
    animation_group.addAnimation(animation2)
    animation_group.start(QParallelAnimationGroup.DeleteWhenStopped)
    print("check4")
    QApplication.processEvents()
    print("check5")
    self.scene.update()
    print("check6")
```

I don't understand if the bounding rectangle I need or not.

I am not getting any error in the debugger. But there is no animation. I am able to get label positions by calling label.scenePos because I want to move the labels with respect to scene only.

```
class bubble:
    def bubbleSort(self, arr):
        n = len(arr)
        # optimize code, so if the array is already sorted, it doesn't need
        # to go through the entire process
        swapped = False
        print(arr)
        # Traverse through all array elements
        for i in range(n - 1):
            print(arr)
            # range(n) also work but outer loop will
            # repeat one time more than needed.
            # Last i elements are already in place
            for j in range(0, n - i - 1):

                # traverse the array from 0 to n-i-1
                # Swap if the element found is greater
                # than the next element
                if arr[j] > arr[j + 1]:
                    swap_larger = arr[j]
                    swap_smaller = arr[j+1]
                    swapped = True
                    arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]
                    sbase.Ui_MainWindow.onbtnclick(self, swap_larger,swap_smaller)

            if not swapped:
                # if we haven't needed to make a single swap, we
                # can just exit the main loop.
                return
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @musicamante hey, I edited my question for minimal reproducible code. I have put comments in there too. Kindly check it again

Comment: Please fix the indentation, as right now it's difficult to distinguish the levels. See how to properly [format code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) and check the post preview before submitting again. Also consider that you're not supposed to edit pyuic generated files (nor "merge" their code in your program), and you should follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) instead.

Comment: [QGraphicsTextItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicstextitem-members.html) _does_ have a `pos` property and `setPos` method that it inherits from QGraphicsObject. In the documentation, sometimes you have to click on link "List of all members, including inherited members".